# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetModuleFileNameEx'

Tags: java, winapi, dll, jna, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am trying to import [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198(VS.85).aspx) in java application. The definition of the function is:

```
DWORD WINAPI GetModuleFileNameEx(
  _In_     HANDLE  hProcess,
  _In_opt_ HMODULE hModule,
  _Out_    LPTSTR  lpFilename,
  _In_     DWORD   nSize
);
```

I translated that into:

```
public abstract DWORD GetModuleFileNameEx(
    WinNT.HANDLE hProcess,
    WinNT.HMODULE hModule,
    char[] pathName,
    WinNT.DWORD pathNameSize
);
```

Which I defined in class like this:

```
 import com.sun.jna.Native;
 import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
 import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
 import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
 import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
 import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;


 public abstract interface Kernel32Ext
   extends Kernel32
 {
   public static final Kernel32Ext INSTANCE = (Kernel32Ext)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32.dll", Kernel32Ext.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
   public abstract DWORD GetModuleFileNameEx(WinNT.HANDLE hProcess, WinNT.HMODULE hModule, char[] pathName, WinNT.DWORD pathNameSize);
 }
```

But when I try to call the method I get an error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Error looking up function 'GetModuleFileNameEx': Uvedená procedura nebyla nalezena.
```

I double checked and according to posts here on stack overflow and other JNA programs, `LPTSTR` correctly translates to `char[]` in JNA API. So there must be something else that is wrong. Am I importing wrong dll, or with wrong options?

I am running this on Windows 7 x64 bit (Czech, hence the non-english error message).

Comment: The exported  function is GetModuleFileNameExW. That's the Unicode variant matching java char[]

Comment: As a note; I checked my own kernel32, and it seems to lack `GetModuleFileNameExW` (on Windows 10), however, loading psapi works, as well as KernelBase. Same Java parameter types, just a different name and dll.

Comment: @jorn this is all documented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function by that name in kernel32 (or elsewhere). See the MSDN page for [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198(v=vs.85).aspx). The function you're looking for is `GetModuleFileNameExW`.

Comment: It imports like that correctly, but I had to import from Psapi.dll instead.

Comment: `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` includes a function name mapper which accounts for `-A` and `-W` suffixes.  Normally it is inappropriate to explicitly indicate `-A` or `-W`; that should only be done where the function signature would be different (usually around usages of character array types).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the full code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.win32.W32APIOptions;

public interface Psapi extends WinNT {
    public static final Psapi INSTANCE = (Psapi)Native.loadLibrary("Psapi.dll", Psapi.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
    public abstract WinDef.DWORD GetModuleFileNameExW(WinNT.HANDLE hProcess, WinNT.HMODULE hModule, char[] pathName, WinNT.DWORD pathNameSize);
}
```

Note that I ended up importing the function from Psapi.dll, not Kernel32.dll.

Example usage, to get filename of a process given a window HWND:

```
  protected WinDef.HWND hwnd;
  @Override
  public String getProcessName() {
    // Refference to int that will later be filled 
    IntByReference pid = new IntByReference(0); 
    // This function gives pid number to the second parameter passed by refference
    UserExt.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);
    // Now get handle to the process 
    // 0x0400 | 0x0010 stands for reading info
    // if you pass 0 you will get error 5 which stands for access denied
    int pidVal = pid.getValue();
    HANDLE process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(0x0400 | 0x0010, false, pidVal);
    if(process==null)
      throw new APIException("Winapi error: "+(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()));
    // Prepare buffer for characters, just as you would 
    // in goold 'ol C program
    char[] path = new char[150];
    DWORD buffSize = new DWORD(path.length);
    // The W at the end of the function name stands for WIDE - 2byte chars
    Psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleFileNameExW(process, null, path, buffSize);
    // convert buffer to java string
    return String.copyValueOf(path);
  }
```